# jQuery's load function doesn't work locally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to load an HTML file in a existing div when the window's width is smaller than 600px.

The code is:

```
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window).width() < 600) {
           $("#testing_div").load("C:/Users/elena/Desktop/Demo/prova.html");
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testing_div"> </div>
</body>
```

I have tested this code on my website and it works, but maybe I am doing something wrong to make it work locally.

Is there a reason why the `load` function doesn't work locally but only on a web server?

Comment: You can't make requests to the local file system - you need to use a web server.

Comment: Your browser console is your best friend. "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." Also where do you link to the jQuery library? It should be between the `<head>` tags

Comment: Imagine what security issues come out if this type of file system access is available from client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is security. Running web pages through `file://` protocol have disabled a lot of features because security issues. You can make a webserver in javascript through Node.js and you can have a webserver in the local without installing apache or something similar.

Node.js webpage:

https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 ways to solve it quickly.

1 - You can download the "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" extension on google chrome.

2 - You can install the wamp program, wamp will simulate a local webserver. In this case, you will access your page using: "localhost/name_of_the_page.html"

Comment: WAMP is overkill for this. A simple Node.js `serve` will suffice.

Comment: ok @Matheus208, but in the future she will put it on webserver.