# Load html page into div with jquery on local machine

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a website where you click on a link and the content of another html file loads into a div. 
I've searched a long while, found lots of info, and made what I think is the simplest test case. Before I upload anything, I want to make sure it works, so I test the code on my local machine (Chrome in Mac OS).

However, all I get in Chrome on my Mac is a link that says "HOME" and nothing happens when I click on it!

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be? 
Is the problem because of the html code, or is it a problem how jQuery is called?

This is the content of the main site (where the link is):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href ="#" id="load_home"> HOME </a>

<div id ="content">        
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("content.html");
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's the content.html

```
<h2>This is content</h2>
<p>This is text!</p>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

/Joakim

PS. This example from W3Schools is similar, and works on their site: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: You need a web server to use `.load()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery's load function doesn't work locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667907/jquerys-load-function-doesnt-work-locally)